# As soon as I increase the limit from the psql DB, axios fails. Why?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a function that reaches out into the DB, gets a record and verifies it. The verification process happens with an API via Axios. (See code at the end).

The limit of records requested from the DB is set to 50. When it is set to 10, the code works fine.

However, anything above 30, I get the following error:

`const status = res.data.data.status; TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')`

I want to stress that Axios works 100% perfectly when the limit is 10. Although, at the end of running 10, my DB says `too many connections for role "DBNAME"`

Am I doing something wrong?

```
const verify = async () => {
    console.log("Reading data from DB for verification...");
    await pool
        .query(
            `
        SELECT * FROM main_leads
        WHERE hunter_uploaded = FALSE 
        AND email_sent = 'false' 
        AND verification is NULL
        limit 50
  `
        )
        .then((data) => {
            const emails = data.rows.map(async (x) => {
                await axios({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: `Verify`,
                })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err.message);
                    })
                    .then(async (res) => {
                        console.log(res.data.data);
                        const status = res.data.data.status;
                        //
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(`${res.email}:` + " " + res.status);
                        //
                        await pool.query(
                            `UPDATE main_leads
                             SET domain_processed = TRUE, verification = $1
                             WHERE ID = $2`,
                            [status, x.id]
                        );
                    });
            });
        });
};

verify();
```

Comment: Looks like your code opens a database connection for every query, without closing or reusing it.

Comment: Should I be using client.query? More importantly, how do I use one pool connection for a loop/map like this? thanks